# How to restore database using sqb files in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I have a file with sqb extension(e.g: clark.sqb),how should i to restore database using the sqb file.thanks!

Answer (score 44):

SQB files are created using RedGate's SQL Backup Tool. They supply a command line tool called *sqb2mtf* that can be used to convert to a native SQL backup that can then be easily restored.

- CMD line tool: http://downloads.red-gate.com/labs/sqb2mtf.zip
- usage: *sqb2mtf inputfile outputfile [password]*
- e.g. *sqb2mtf "d:\backups\pubs.sqb" "e:\data\pubs.bak"*

Comment: * GUI interface: http://downloads.red-gate.com/labs/SQBConverterGUI.zip * Wiki: http://labs.red-gate.com/index.php/SQL_Backup_to_MTF_Converter

Comment: Dead wiki link in the comment. Use SQL Backup to MTF Converter located here: http://www.red-gate.com/labs/free-tools/

Comment: Hi Nick, I am trying to find a process to automate the process instead of using a tool so that I could update data in Microsoft SQL Server. Is sql2mtf some what automated process that I could schedule to run?

Answer (score 5):

SQB files are a SQL Server backup format created by [Red Gate's SQL Backup Pro](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-backup/) software.

As mentioned in [Nick Sturgess' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3938761/4480), there are command line and GUI tools available for converting SQB files into regular SQL Server backup files that can then be restored normally.

Additionally, if you have [SQL Backup Pro's server components](http://www.red-gate.com/help/sqlbackup/topics/SBU_InstallnNotes.html) installed on your SQL Server, **you can restore a database from SQB files directly** using a stored procedure call like the following:

```
EXEC master..sqlbackup '-sql "RESTORE DATABASE [MyDatabase] FROM DISK = [C:\backups\*.sqb] LATEST_ALL WITH RECOVERY"'
```

That command will restore the latest possible backup of the `MyDatabase` database from all of the SQB files in `C:\backups\`. So, if you have a handful of full backups, differential backups, and transactional backups all kept in C:\backups, this command will automatically calculate the latest backup that can be restored without you having to select the correct files manually and without having to convert the SQB files to another format.

There are a number of different options that can be used to restore your database from SQB files directly, including:

- Restoring to a database with a different name than that of the database in the backup
- Relocating where the MDF and LDF files should be stored (useful if the server you're restoring to is different from the server where the backup was taken)

All of these options (and more) are outlined on [Red Gate's syntax example page](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content/SQL_Backup/help/7.2/SBU_Toolkit_syntax_egs#o15223).

Comment: Is this the only solution that I don't have to manually run the task? I am trying to automate the process.

Answer (score 3):

I think that's a Red Gate SQLBackup file - have a look [here](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_backup/index_2.htm) for more information.  You should be able to download a trial to try the restore.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Just another quick answer - if you have the Redgate SQL Backup application installed, you can do all this through their application and you don't have to mess with commands.

Tools --> Utilities --> SQL Backup File Converter

[image: Using the Backup SQL Backup RedGate Application]