# Use of an SQB file in Windows

Tags: mysql, sql, windows

Is there any way to use/view the contents of a .SQB file at all using a Windows (8) computer? I have this database backup sent to me from a client running Windows Server 2003 and I know they can be converted into a BAK file, but I still don't understand how I can make use of it without having Windows Server.

Is there literally any way this can be viewed or even uploaded to a MySQL database perhaps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restore database using sqb files in SQL SERVER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861334/how-to-restore-database-using-sqb-files-in-sql-server)

Comment: It isn't a duplicate, I'm not using an SQL server, but rather a MySQL server.

Comment: You need to specify the source of your file then. Extensions are, in the grand scheme, meaningless.

Comment: Please clarify, which database does your customer use?